# Efficient alternative to using Managed API in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, import

So if I directly use kernel32 to delete my file as an example, would it be more efficient alternative to this C# API?

```
System.IO.File.Delete(string Path);
```

If I import the dll like so and just use DeleteFile("C:.."):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool DeleteFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpFileName);
```

Will it be better in effeciency e.g Time it takes to execute the code?

Comment: That looks like micro optimizing. Do you really need to delete files very very quickly?

Comment: Deleting a file is an I/O operation that takes very little CPU, I suspect you won't see any difference in timing at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a fairly common misconception that managed code is slow.  In general it is not, you execute the same kind of code that a C compiler produces, machine code.  It is especially not relevant with a large number of the kind of .Net framework classes that are wrappers for operating system functions.

Like the File class.  The File.Delete() method in fact pinvokes the DeleteFile() winapi function.  Necessarily so, that's the only way to delete a file on Windows.  There is nothing the .NET framework could do, at least not until a managed operating system becomes available.  Which may actually happen some day, the super-secret Midori project at Microsoft aims to develop just such an operating system.

But that's future-music, right now it is a big chunk of C code, buried in a file system driver like Fat32 or NTFS that actually gets the job done.  It operates at disk speeds, DeleteFile() doesn't return until the file system driver confirmed that the deletion is completed.  Which is very, very slow.  Like around 50 milliseconds for an old-fashioned hard drive, in the sub-millisecond range for an SSD.

File.Delete() **does** add code, it performs lots of error checking.  If verifies that the argument you pass isn't null, checks if your code isn't running in a sandbox that denies file deletion right, checks if you didn't specify any characters in the path that are not legal in a file path, converts an incremental path to a full path and checks that it is still a legal path, checks if the path string isn't too long, converts short MS-Dos 8.3 names to long names if necessary.

That's a bunch of work but that's measured in *microseconds*.  If you pinvoke DeleteFile then you'll skip that code but you'll only make it ~1% faster, at best.  What you'll lose is **reliability**, the guarantee that if you have an oops in your code or data that you are going to be told about it.  With a very clear exception message that tells you exactly what is wrong.  Extremely valuable because those few microseconds multiplied by a billion is still no match for the amount of time and suffering you'll expend on debugging a DeleteFile() that didn't work.

Don't do it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to know for sure is to test it. Write code that creates a whole bunch of temp files, and then time how long it takes to delete them all.

The performance considerations here:

- any possible performance gain from using the native api for file deletion (`kernel32`) vs
- the performance loss from having to use marshalling.

It would be my hunch that any performance gain would be minor, if you were to get one at all.

Comment: While this is generally true, in this specific case I have to go with "any overhead is, for all practical purposes, entirely mitigated by the cost of the operation". Also, the standard .NET method has to talk to the OS natively at some level ..

Comment: I totally agree; it would definitely be the file I/O that would slow you down here, and thus any performance gains would be insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

The limiting factor of a delete operation is performing the filesystem operation, not the code that connects your C# code to the OS code. You will see no discernable difference between these two calls. Switching to calling kernel32 directly in this API would definitely be a premature optimization.